# TTimer - вспоминия Delphi

Tags: delphi

Доброго всем.
Я совсем забыл Delphi программирование.
Что я делаю не так?
Label1 не показывает оставшееся время.

```
Timer_interval:= 10000;
....
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender:TObject);
var
  timer_click: integer;

begin

  timer_click:=Timer_interval-1;

  if timer_click > 0 then
    begin
      Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(timer_click);
    end
  else
    begin
      Button2.Enabled:=True;
      timer1.Enabled:=False;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: @I_CaR, вы, например, не уменьшаете значение переменной `Timer_interval`. Поэтому у вас таймер будет показывать одно и то же.

Comment: @Nofate, Вспомнил про трассеровку даже!  
Трассеровка показывает, что я всё правильно отнимаю.  
А то что за 10 секунд 10 000 прорисовок, в Label может из-за этого что?

Comment: Обновлять чаще, чем раз в 100-200 миллисекунд особого смысла нет.

Comment: Label1.Caption:='10000'; //Начальное значение,например, 10000
.....

Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(StrToInt(Label1.Caption)-1);

Comment: @I_CaR, есть такой косяк у delphi-приложений. Перед тем как копировать, переключайтесь на русский язык. И все скопируется как надо.

Answer (score 3):

При каждом вызове события `OnTimer()` переменная `timer_click` заново объявляется и равна `Timer_interval-1` т.е. 9999. Переменную `timer_click` нужно объявлять за пределами видимости события `OnTimer()`

```
Timer_interval:= 10000;
timer_click: integer;
timer_click := Timer_interval;
....
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender:TObject);
begin

  //timer_click:=timer_click-1;
  Dec(timer_click);

  if timer_click > 0 then
    begin
      Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(timer_click);
    end
  else
    begin
      Button2.Enabled:=True;
      timer1.Enabled:=False;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

[[@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate)](/users/1984/nofate) ♦ [[@Oleg53](/users/4509/oleg53)](/users/4509/oleg53)
ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ!!!
Только от 10 000 я же отнимаю 1, каждые 10 секунд!!!!
Сейчас подправлю!
Т.е. у меня наоборот было 1 изменение label раз в 10 сек!

---

```
Timer_interval:=20;
........
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  Timer_interval:=Timer_interval-1;
  if Timer_interval > 0 then
    begin
      Label2.Caption:=IntToStr(Timer_interval)+' сек.';
    end
  else
    begin
      Button2.Enabled:=True;
      timer1.Enabled:=False;
      MessageDlg('Доступ на выбор и чтение лекций открыт.',mtInformation , [mbYes], 0);
    end;
end;
```

---